# Execute JS script from anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script Javascript (whatever it does) and I need to run it directly from anypage i am surfing on, maybe with a button on my bookmarks, or an extension.

I have absolutly no idea on how should I do that, I tried to search a bit but no idea where to begin. That's why I'm asking here for a bit of an help ! :D

It would be lovely from anyone of you to help me through !

Comment: When you say any page do you mean sites outside of your application that you do NOT own?

Comment: [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at web browser extensions, which allow executing of JavaScript code on web sites, where you enabled it:

- [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) for any browser
- [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox

You can find examples of such scripts at [user script hosting](https://wiki.greasespot.net/User_Script_Hosting) web sites, for example:

- [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/)
- [OpenUserJS](http://userscripts-mirror.org/)
- [userscripts.org](http://userscripts-mirror.org/)

You can also register and maintain your script there, so that the others can find it and install it from there.